# CloudBees and OS X "Unable to provision osx : No such vm type allowed"

Tags: ios, macos, continuous-integration, cloud, cloudbees

With a free account in the CloudBees site, i created a Job with an osx configuration, i added the tag "osx" for the slave node restriction and all was working fine, until now.

Today i received this message when i tried to build a mobile app on the osx slave node "Unable to provision osx : No such vm type allowed", this message shown on the "DEV@cloud Slave Provisioning" section, i also tried changing the configuration of the OS X slave node template to "small", "standard" and "high speed" and with the three options i received the same message.

Somebody can help me with this problem? or somebody knows why the system is showing me this message now?, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note: if you need OS X CI/CD support [Bitrise](http://www.bitrise.io/) has a free account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSX builds are now longer available on free DEV@cloud accounts. You must upgrade to either Pro or Enterprise.